# How do i change the port an heroku server runs on?

Tags: node.js, heroku, ssl-certificate, heroku-cli

I just configured my server to support https with an SSL certificate and i'm getting this weird error in my heroku logs.

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::23736`

```
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810153+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::23736
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810155+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810157+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810160+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810162+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:103:12)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810163+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810166+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810168+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810170+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810171+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810174+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810176+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event at:
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810178+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810180+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810182+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810184+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.810186+00:00 app[web.1]:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-07-02T20:29:56.819819+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-07-02T20:29:56.820414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-07-02T20:29:56.822143+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! gbahdeyboh@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2019-07-02T20:29:56.822348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-07-02T20:29:56.822671+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2019-07-02T20:29:56.822893+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the gbahdeyboh@1.0.0 start script.
2019-07-02T20:29:56.823098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-07-02T20:29:56.829332+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-07-02T20:29:56.829583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-07-02T20:29:56.829738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-07-02T20_29_56_825Z-debug.log
2019-07-02T20:29:56.895827+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-02T20:29:56.902570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-02T20:29:56.878861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Is there a way to change what port heroku servers listen on?

Comment: maybe this error happened after the configuration you made ? if that's the case then please tell us more details about these configuration so we can assist you better

Comment: "I just configured my server to support https with an SSL certificate"—how? Normally this wouldn't cause the error you describe.

Comment: It turned out I forgot to comment the line of code that listens to http request's before I added an https listener. Since both http and https listens on a port specified on the production environment variable, the port becomes used by one of the two before the second listener gets fired, which was why i got the "address already in use" error